# How to use exponents using a for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, integer, exponent

I am working on a functions HW for my programming class and Im trying to write a function that will allow me to do exponent math (in a simple form). (Oh and I can't use the actual exponent function, I have to write my own function using for loops, if statements or other things like that.)
EX: user enters base and then enters the power to raise it by. So the user enters:
5
3
it should be 5 to the 3rd power, so it should output 125 (5x5x5). However my for loop is not working properly. How should I structure my for loop to properly handle exponent math? 
code:
int main(){

```
int base, pow;

scanf("%d", &base);
scanf("%d", &pow);

int i;
for (i=0; i<=pow; i++) {
    i *= base;
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

printf("%d", i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're using the same variable for the loop and the result. You don't want to do that.

```
int j = 1;
for(i =  0; i < pow; i++)
{
      j*= base;
}
```

Is what you want. You're also off by one on the loop count. With i <= pow you have

i=0, j * 5 = 5, i=1

i=1, j * 5 = 25,i=2

i=2, j * 5 = 125,i=3. This is where you want to stop but 3 <= 3 so it goes again.

i=3, j *5 = 625,i=4. 4 is not <= 3 so it will then stop here.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is obviously wrong:

```
for (i=0; i<=pow; i++) {
    i *= base;
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

You are multiplying the loop counter by base for some reason, which will not yield any good.
The right one would be:

```
int result = 1;
for (i=0; i < pow; i++) {
    result *= base;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an accumulator that starts at 1 and is multiplied by the base each time.  This accumulator should also not be i (since this will change at each step of the for loop).

Try

```
int base, pow;

scanf("%d", &base);
scanf("%d", &pow);

int i, accumulator;
accumulator = 1
for (i=0; i<pow; i++) {
  accumulator *= base;
  printf("%d\n", accumulator);
}

printf("%d", accumulator);
```

Comment: You have one extra iteration in your loop.